# Is it possible to set the precision of floats in a DataFrame based on it's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame 'df':

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
          0
0  1000.000
1     0.395
2     1.530
3     1.200
4     0.550
```

I want numbers greater than one to show two decimal places and numbers less than one to show four like so:

```
         0
0  1000.00
1    0.395
2     1.53
3     1.20
4    0.550
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pd.set_option('display.float_format', your_format)`
where `your_format = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(2 if x > 1 else 4).format(x)`

Or you can use `pd.option_context` to set temporarily

```
your_format = lambda x: '{{:0.{}f}}'.format(2 if x > 1 else 4).format(x)
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', your_format):
    print(df)

        0
0 1000.00
1  0.3950
2    1.53
3    1.20
4  0.5500
```